# Why am I getting console error 'Refusing to load the font'?

Tags: css, font-face

I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting a console error that states the browser is refusing to load font.

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
            font-family: 'gt_walsheimmedium';
            src: url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.eot.html');
            src: url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.eot-.html#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.woff.html') format('woff'), url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.ttf.html') format('truetype'), url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.svg.html#gt_walsheimmedium') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
```

1. Why is this happening? In layman terms please?
2. What effect will this have as I'm currently working locally?

Error below

```
[Error] Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAIw4ABEAAAABQcAAAQABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABHUE9TAAABgAAACU8AABMOD1XXMEdTVUIAAArQAAAAUwAAAHCOOI56T1MvMgAACyQAAABbAAAAYNrnrZBjbWFwAAALgAAAAIEAAAC0jBiQAGN2dCAAAAwEAAAAKgAAAC4HyBmgZnBnbQAADDAAAAOBAAAG5XJackBnYXNwAAAPtAAAAAwAAAAMAA0AGGdseWYAAA/AAABViQAAvQzAr6AGaGVhZAAAZUwAAAA2AAAANvzd8kdoaGVhAABlhAAAAB8AAAAkD/YHpGhtdHgAAGWkAAACFAAAA26BW0HVa2VybgAAZ7gAAB/3AABeRKoEucNsb2NhAACHsAAAAb4AAAG+1eip6m1heHAAAIlwAAAAIAAAACAByAf2bmFtZQAAiZAAAADEAAABYBoFNRJwb3N0AACKVAAAAZYAAAJBVvgNXnByZ...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I'm not clear with Content Securoty Policy even after Googling and reading about it.

Comment: Why do you have "html" as an extension on the fonts?

Comment: It came with the style sheet from the foundry? Is it not needed?

Comment: it seems not correct. please check the font files in the filesystem if they have .eot file ending or .eot.html

Comment: Removed .html. Problem unresolved though. I have and have had 4 console errors but I'm loading 3 fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would do the trick:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'gt_walsheimmedium';
    src: url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.eot');
    src: url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('gt-walsheim-medium-web-webfont.svg#gt_walsheimmedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: because like mentioned in the comment to the original post font files usually do not end on .html

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the explanation to the answer itself. A good answer does not begin with "I guess"... If you have to guess, then you should comment and wait for the OP to reply.